# How to eslint a Web Component which includes another component?

Tags: polymer, eslint

I'm trying to eslint my Polymer Web Components, but every time I link another Component or Behavior, the usage thereof will be highlighted with a *no-undef* error.
Of course I could add the following comment to any line with a no-undef error that is caused by includes, as a work-around:

```
// eslint-disable-line no-undef
```

But that's ugly, cumbersome and frustrating. Obviously, I don't want to completely disable *no-undef*.

Is there any solution I am failing to google? Any alternatives for eslint that work with Polymer **and** MS Visual Studio Code?

Comment: try using polylint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer team [recommends](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-linter#use-with-other-tools) to use:

1. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-linter
2. Together with eslint

The polymer lintier is integrated in the [Polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli).

This also applies to the upcoming Polymer 3 which is more ES6 centred.